# Can not use zomatopy in my Python Flask app

Tags: python, flask, visual-studio-code, windows-10

In my Python Flask App I tried to install and use module `zomatopy` after reading this:

https://github.com/sharadbhat/Zomatopy

After that I tried it in a simple code in my root route like this:

```
app = Flask(__name__)

config = {
        "user_key": "my_defined_user_key"
}
    
zomato = zomatopy.initialize_app(config)
    
@app.route('/homepage')
def home():
    category_dictionary = zomato.get_categories()
    city_ID = zomato.get_city_ID("Belgrade")
    city_name = zomato.get_city_name(city_ID)
    return render_template('base.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

But I keep getting this error(after a lot of reading and trying):

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'zomatopy'
```

Thanks.

Comment: What information does the page and console display after using 'python -m flask run'?Try to use 'pip list' to check whether module 'zomatopy' is successfully installed in your virtual environment. In addition, if you could provide more relevant configuration and file directory information, it will be better to solve it. You could refer to it to check the use steps:https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/tutorial-flask#_prerequisites

Comment: @JillCheng 'pip list' shows me installed modules including zomatopy 1.0.10. After I run 'python -m flask run' I get a message 'ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'zomatopy''

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When i use 'pip install zomatopy' to download and install module 'zomatopy', the name and content of the package installed by this method are not accurate.

(In the pip installation list of the current virtual environment, the package name is 'zomatopy-1.0.10.dist-info', not 'zomatopy'.).

You could try to download the 'zomatopy' in your link and put it in the same folder location as 'zomatopy-1.0.10.dist-info'.

If there is a wavy line, please reload VSCode.

In addition, pay attention to the use of virtual environments.

Reference: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/tutorial-flask#_create-a-project-environment-for-the-flask-tutorial

Comment: I guess that is the only thing left for me to do, thank you Sir. Kind Regards.